# Не срабатывает Converter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Конвертер срабатывает только при изменении первой привязки. При изменении ListBox.SelectedItem ничего не происходит.

```
                <Button.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AddToAlbumButtonVisibility}">
                        <Binding ElementName="mainTab"
                                 Path="SelectedIndex">
                        </Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="listBox"
                                 Path="SelectedItem">
                        </Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.Visibility>
```

**Converter**

```
 public class AddToAlbumButtonVisibility : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var listBoxItem = values[1] as ListBoxItem;
        if (listBoxItem != null)
        {
            var path = listBoxItem.Tag.ToString();

            if (values[0].Equals(1) && File.Exists(path))
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**ListBox**

```
                           <ListBox Name="listBox"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"
                                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto"
                                 Margin="2"
                                 Background="Black">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True">
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Tag="{Binding FullPath}">
                                        <Label.Content>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                                Width="100"
                                                Margin="5">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}">
                                                </Image>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                   Foreground="White"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Label.Content>
                                        <Label.ToolTip>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                        </Label.ToolTip>
                                    </Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseDoubleClick" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <ListBox.SelectionMode>
                                <Binding ElementName="toogleButton"
                                         Path="IsChecked"
                                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                    <Binding.Converter>
                                        <conv:ListBoxSelectedModeConverter></conv:ListBoxSelectedModeConverter>
                                    </Binding.Converter>
                                </Binding>
                            </ListBox.SelectionMode>
                        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Почему у вас написано `var listBoxItem = values[1] as ListBoxItem; if (listBoxItem != null)`. Предполагается, что в `values[1]` может быть что-то другое?

Comment: @VladD, нет, в `values[1]` может быть только `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: Тогда почему `as` и проверка на `null`?

Comment: @VladD, сложно ответить, наверное из-за какого-то моего недопонимания. В конвертер приходит object, разве не нужно привестись к конкретному типу?

Comment: Да, но для этого есть два пути. Если вы уверены в том, что будет тип `ListBoxItem`, то вы делаете каст: `var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)values[1]; var path = listBoxItem.Tag.ToString();` и т. д. Проверку через `as` + тест на `null` нужно делать, когда там может быть и другой тип.

Comment: В вашем случае, если там реально окажется другой тип, то вы не зайдёте в `if`, и ошибка будет молча проигнорирована. Таким образом вы не узнаете, что что-то идёт не так.

Comment: @VladD, действительно, приходит другой обьект. `Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.`

Comment: Вот, видите? :) Тогда делайте лучше не так: привязывайтесь к `Tag`'у. Получится вот что: `<Binding ElementName="listBox" Path="SelectedItem.Tag">`. И в `values[1]` тогда по идее должен быть `Tag`. Попробуйте!

Comment: @VladD, все равно приходит `'MS.Internal.NamedObject'`

Comment: Хм. Сейчас попробую, момент.

Comment: @VladD, а может быть проблема из-за того что в `Listbox` переопределенный `ItemsPanel и ItemTemplate`?

Comment: Покажите код вашего `ListBox`'а. Я попробовал, у меня код работает.

Comment: Кстати, проверка `File.Exists` в конвертере — это ужас. Подумайте, почему ваша программа будет подвисать.

Comment: @VladD, с `File.Exists` что-то придумаю:) `ListBox` добавил.

Comment: С `File.Exists` ничего придумывать не надо, эта функциональность должна быть не в View, а в модели. :-\

Comment: Ну, с новым кодом ко мне в конвертер приходит VM-объект. А вам почему-то нет, странно.

Comment: @VladD, а может быть такое что байдинг срабатывает до того как создался VM?

Comment: @VladD, я так подумал, так как `ListBox` сидит в `TabContro`l. А привязка идет к  обоим одновременно. Когда меняется `SelectedIndex` в `TabControl`, то `ListBox` еще ничего  не успевает отобразить.